# I am Trying To make a loop so that it can make a graph of outlier of every feature

Tags: python

can anybudy help me in making of this loop
[image]

```
 for i in dn:
    print (dn[i].plot.box(grid=True))
```

there are many feature in dn but it is making only one featur's outlier.

Comment: Can you clarify what the issue is? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: @AMC  it showing only one plot of one feature but there are alot of features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems when you are doing print for plot Jupiter overrides them, so you can see only the last plot. Please try to do:

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    for i in dn:
        dn[i].plot.box(grid=True)
        plt.show()
```